# How get the length of the ORC file being written?

Tags: java, hive, orc

I'm writing data to an ORC file. I want to get the length of this file. (including data that has been flush and the data that's still in the buff cache) What should I do, please? I don't want to close the file immediately.
I use JAVA.

Comment: Currently, we do this by estimating the size of the file ourselves. For details, see https://github.com/apache/iceberg/pull/3784.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do precisely that.  The [javadoc](https://orc.apache.org/api/orc-core/org/apache/orc/impl/WriterImpl.html#getRawDataSize--) for the `Writer.getRawDataSize` method states:

> Raw data size will be compute when writing the file footer. Hence raw data size value will be available only after closing the writer.

And there isn't an explicit `flush` method in the API.

However, the `WriterImpl` classes add a `writeIntermediateFooter` method ([javadoc](https://orc.apache.org/api/orc-core/org/apache/orc/impl/WriterImpl.html#writeIntermediateFooter--)) that appears to<sup>1</sup> flush the data added so far to disk.  If you used the method's return value, that would probably be a good estimate of the current file size.

<sup>1 - I am making some assumptions about how the method achieves what it is described as doing.</sup>

Comment: I want to judge whether to open a new file by the size of the file being written. Similar to the rolling writer. If I can't get the file size, then I can't tell if I should close it. Is there any other way? thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know if there is another way.  I guess, you could try looking at the library source code to see if you can figure out another way.  (Or even modifying it!)  But the `writeIntermediateFooter` approach looks like it should do what you need.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks again. The writeIntermediateFooter flushes stripes immediately. If I invoke this method frequently, a lot of stripes are generated in the file, which may not be friendly. I have thought about maintaining a cache of data length. Each time receive a piece of data, calculate the actual length of the data that will be written to the orc file. But I haven't figured out how to work out this length yet.

Comment: Well yes ... this is the problem.  Predicting what the length would be without flushing out the stripes would be immensely complicated.  To be practical you need to choose between flushing frequently (to get an accurate size) or doing it infrequently and potentially going over your limit.

Comment: (Or allowing a enough slack in your limits that you don't go over ...)